# Why the more a label is out of lm_more div

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have a web homepage.

I want to set a more link to the news page. But the more `<a>` link is exceeding the `lm_more` `.

The picture is like:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

The code is like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Web home page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/format.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen">
<link href="./css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper-4.5.0/dist/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery_min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/video.js"></script>
<script src="swiper-4.5.0/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {      
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'horizontal', 
  loop: true,
  history: 'love',
  roundLengths : true,
  parallax : true,

  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable :true,
  },
  autoplay: {
    stopOnLastSlide: true,
  },
  navigation: {
  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  paginationClickable :true,
  })
 })
 </script>

<body style="background:url(./image/taiyi.jpg); height:100%;width:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat">

<style>
  body{
  margin:0;
  }
  .content{
    margin-left:auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 1400px;
    height:850px;
    background-color:white;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
 .content .uprow{
   width: 1400px;
   height: 400px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }
 .content .uprow .upright{
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   float: right;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #999;
 }
.lm_title_con{
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.lm_title_con .lm_title{
  width: 85px;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #3E6BC0;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6BC0;
}
.lm_more{
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.lm_more a{
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
.swiper-container{
  width: 595px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
</style>

<div class="content">
  <div class="uprow">
    <div class="upright">
      <div class="lm_title_con">
        <div class="lm_title">
          news
        </div>
        <div class="lm_more">
          <a href="">more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:red"><a href='' ><img src='image/news/20190819-1png' style="width:595px;height:340px" alt=''></a></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:blue"><a href='../newsdetail/news20190729.html' ><img src='image/news/20190729-1jpg' style="width:595px;height:340px" alt=''></a></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:green"><a href='../newsdetail/news20190530.html' ><img src='image/news/20190530-1png' style="width:595px;height:340px" alt=''></a></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:yellow"><a href='../newsdetail/news20190529.html' ><img src='image/news/20190529-1png' style="width:595px;height:340px" alt=''></a></div>      
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I Comment  the content div, It is OK

```
<!--<div class="content">-->
      <div class="uprow">
       </div>
  <!--</div>-->
```

The result picture is like:

[image: The more is in lm_more]

But the other `<div>` position is changed, and the homepage size is messed up! Who can help me?

Comment: Why do not you use a bootstrap? With Bootstrap Nav

Answer (score 0):

Please add "box-sizing" property in your ".lm_title_con" class selector.

Please try below CSS.

```
.lm_title_con {
 width: 600px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box; /* new added */
}
```

[image]